# .tooltip() is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, tooltip

I am trying to use the .tooltip() that I found from the following: [Jquery-ui tooltip](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip). What I have is a rails app that has some information in a table. In separate cells. Currently you can view the full information of a cell by clicking it which opens up jquery dialog which works fine. What I am trying to add to it is so that there will be two options.

- 1) Click the cell which brings up jquery dialog - which works already
- 2) Or hover a cell which shows an overview.

[Image](http://postimage.org/image/mgbvm096t/)

From the image currently you have a booking that you can click on and it will show the booking information. However I am trying to extend it so that the user has the option of clicking to view the information or hovering over the cell to view the information.

What is the best way to do this? I have the following code which works with and brings up the dialog. I tried adding:

```
<td class="<%= booking.status %>" onmouseover='$("#booking<%= booking.id %>").tooltip()'>
```

before  which didn't work, and I probably understand that it wouldn't work because there would be a conflict between the two. In addition to this I did try using simpletip and qtip but seemed to not have no luck. Is what I am trying to do not feasible.

```
<td class="<%= booking.status %>" onclick='$("#booking<%= booking.id %>").dialog()'>
  <center>
  <%= booking.reference_number %>
  <% if current_user.is_booking_manager? %>
    (<%= booking.company_name %>)
  <% end %>
</center>
<div style="display:none;">
  <% if not booking.provisional? or current_user.is_booking_manager? %>
    <div id="booking<%= booking.id %>" title="Booking Information">
  <% else %>
    <div id="booking<%= booking.id %>" title="Edit Booking">
  <% end %>
      <%= render :partial => "booking_dialog", :locals => { :booking => booking } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: try moving `$("#some").tooltip();` to `$(document).ready(function() { $("#some").tooltip(); });`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try doing something like this. For tooltip to work, you will require `title` set for the control.

**HTML**

```
<td id="bookingTd" title="This is a tooltip." 
     class="<%= booking.status %>" 
     onclick='$("#booking<%= booking.id %>").dialog()'>

</td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#bookingTd").tooltip();
});
```

Also make sure you load jQuery first and then the tooltip plugin.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I did try what you suggested which now makes my code look like the following: http://pastie.org/3431452 and had no luck. Whats strange is that I also have jquery.tooltip.js in my assets/javascript folder

Comment: Also check other js included in the demo page. <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
 <script src="../../jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
 <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
 <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
 <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
 <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js"></script>

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2SWmm/1/) jsFiddle. Here i have added all resources and it is working :)

Comment: For some reason I put the example in and it isn't working for me I am getting the following error in jquery.ui.tooltip: `$.widget is not a function
_destroy: function() {` and I just used yours as an example. I also included all js and the css with it

Comment: I have used [this](http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid0FDCA3AC3AC9C24C2B312B1EA47F9C3E9CEB94B4.aspx) jQuery Plugin. This works similarly. Try this. Hope this works for you. It only needs basic jQuery.js.

Comment: Should I include this along with the other files?

Answer (score 20):

I got rid of the error by adding the boostrap libs & css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case i was uploading two versions of jquery:
jquery 3.4 before the tooltip code, and jquery 3.5 after the tooltip code.
i removed the second upload of jquery(3.5) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Bootstrap 4, use `.min.js` jquery file in place of `.slim.min.js` file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, `tooltip()` has not *always existed in jQuery UI*.  Specifically...

> version added: 1.9 (Source: **[API.jQueryUI.com: Tooltip Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**.)

If you don't have a version of jQuery UI at version 1.9 or higher, you'll get the error: `tooltip() is not a function()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it took me an hour to recognise that the syntax has changed in Bootstrap 5. It's not `tooltip()` anymore, but `Tooltip()` instead. Also jQuery isn't required anymore.

> ### Example: Enable tooltips everywhere
>
> One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them
> by their data-bs-toggle attribute:
>
> ```js
> var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
> var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
>   return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
> })
> ```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/